# Ownership and move semantics

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Given the following definition of an owner, does it make any sense to talk about move semantics for objects that do not own resources?

https://www.stroustrup.com/resource-model.pdf

> An owner is an object containing a pointer to an object allocated by new for which a delete is required.

Stated in another way, does it make any sense to explicitly define move constructor and move assignment operators for an object that does not hold a pointer to an object that is allocated on the heap?

Thanks

Comment: It makes sense for any object containing a resource that needs to be cleaned up (I've done it for wrapper objects that contained OpenGL id's, file descriptors are another good one)

Comment: "Owner" might not be a good word. Such objects have _borrowed_ a resource, and you need a destructor to return the resource when you're done borrowing it. `new` just borrows memory from the heap. "Moving" also means that you hand over the responsibility to return the borrowed resource to the lender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely. The definition quoted is a simplification. In general, any API that works with an acquire/release pattern can support move semantics. As a C++11 example, `std::unique_lock` is a movable object. It owns a mutex, not a heap allocation. The acquire/release methods are `.lock` and `.unlock` instead of `new` and `delete`.

Comment: So in general, can we safely say that it makes sense ONLY for objects that can acquire and release a resource(s) — whatever that resource(s) may be?

Comment: @user3124390 it does not need to be a resource, having an object that is not copy- but only moveable can also make sense in other situations, e.g. if the object represents an identity. And there are for sure other things that can express owensership and are not directly related to resoruces.

Comment: @user3124390: No. That;s incorrect logic. You originally wondered if it's just `new/delete`. I showed that there is a larger category (anything with acquire/release behavior) which includes `new/delete`. I do not show (or claim) that this is the largest such category.

Comment: @user3124390: Also, you write "resource(s)". There's a well-known principle that every C++ owner object should manage exactly one owned resource. This might be an array, as in `std::vector<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<T[ ]>`, but the resource has to be releasable with a single call. If you need more resources, you nest owners, e.g. `std::vector<std::string>`. This guarantees all allocated resources are released when an exception happens, because exactly one dtor runs per successfully allocated resource.

Comment: Doesn't `There's a well-known principle that every C++ owner object should manage exactly one owned resource` contradict with `std::vector` (or at least the `std::vector<std::string>` example)  because it owns multiple objects? (which wouldn't be different to a `struct foo { std::string str1; std::string str2}`?

Comment: @t.niese: `std::vector<T>` can release its array with a single call to `std::allocator<T>::deallocate()`. Your `struct foo` does not even _own_ a single resource, but both of its members do. Basically, C++ has ctor/dtor semantics which work correctly for multiple sub-objects, even in the presence of exceptions. But if you have a resource that does not natively have ctor/dtor semantics, you wrap that resource in an "owner" class (one resource per instance). `vector` and `string` are pre-wrapped owner classes.